# App Script how to customize a non-error message in doGet()

Tags: google-apps-script

**[edited]**

I have a doGet() function that searches for a specific timestamp from a Gsheet and update that row's status based on what the approver clicked in the email (i.e. approved or disapproved).

Searching and updating work perfectly but the custom message I want to convey to the Approver is a bit confusing because the tab shows "Error" and a reference to the code's line number. Please refer to screenshot below:

[image: Here's a screenshot]

It might be because I'm using "throw" to show my custom message so I'd like to know the right way to show custom message.  I've seen posts in try/catch but I couldn't understand how it is used for this case where there's actually no error.
Will appreciate any help. And apologies for this newbie question.

Snippet of my code is below:

```
function doGet(e) {
....
  // now search again using the adjusted timestamp
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i][1].toString().indexOf(revisedtimestamp);
    if (row > -1) {   //found
       var a = i;
       sheet.getRange(a + 1, approvalCol).setValue(e.parameter.approval);
       throw ("Your decision has been sent to the requestor cc: Finance for processing");  
       break;
    } else {          //not found
      throw ("There is a problem locating this request. Finance is automatically notified to look into this.");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello @TomR, which is the line questions? And what error message are you getting? Could you provide more details regarding this? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @ale13 for responding. I edited my post and added screenshot for clarity. There is actually no error because the search was successful. The "Error" in the tab may be because I used throw to show my custom message. Is there a better/right way to do it?

Comment: Read about the [Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. I had explored that but my understanding is that I can't use it because my case is a web app? doGet() is triggered through a hyperlink in the Approver's email. Had also tried using Browser. MsgBox but the tab shows "Error"and the text "The script completed but did not return anything" instead of my custom message --- in spite of a successful search & update.

Comment: I think this might be a good application for a Gmail Addon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I found a [reference](http://googleappscripting.com/doget-dopost-tutorial-examples/) for web apps using HtmlService.createHtmlOutput or ContentService.createTextOutput for this purpose. So I replaced throw with these lines:

```
var HTMLString = "<style> h1,p {font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial'}</style>"
+ "<h1>Approval process completed.<br>"
+ UImsgForApprover + "</h1><p>";

HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString);
return HTMLOutput
```

My custom message shows nicely enough for my needs, as shown below.
ContentService.createTextOutput also works ok, it's just unformatted text.

[image]